# Ensure that application will launch on 64 bit JVM if exists

Tags: java, jvm

I'm running a java application from java application using this code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java -jar launcher.jar", null, new File(installDir));
```

Is there any way to ensure that application will use 64-bit version of JRE if both are installed?

Comment: You're gonna get whatever's set in `java.home`.

Comment: I just want it to launch as 64-bit application. No matter the way.

Comment: I think there's a way to examine the registry and *sometimes* find them all.  Except that Oracle bobbled a couple of recent Java upgrades and semi-trashed the registry info & associated directories.

Comment: For now I'll use just searching in `java.home` string `(x86)` and removning it, still looking for a better way to do this.